# Mocking and verifying SLF4J with JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, slf4j, jmockit

I have a class with SLF4J logger instanced like:

```
 public class MyClass {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void foo() {
      log.warn("My warn");
    }
  }
```

And I need to test it with JMockit like:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldLogWarn(@Mocked Logger log) throws Exception {
   new Expectations() {{
     log.warn(anyString);
   }};
   MyClass my = new MyClass();
   my.foo(); 
 }
```

After searching a lot I figured out, I need to use MockUp somehow. But can't get it how exactly.

Btw, I'm using last version of JMockit(1.29) where you no more can **setField(log)** for final static fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### JMockit has the [`@Capturing`](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Capturing.html) annotation that works for this situation

> Indicates a mock field or a mock parameter for which all classes extending/implementing the mocked type will also get mocked.
>
> *Future* instances of a capturing mocked type (ie, instances created sometime later during the test) will become associated with the mock field/parameter. When recording or verifying expectations on the mock field/parameter, these associated instances are regarded as equivalent to the original mocked instance created for the mock field/parameter.

This means that if you annotate it with `@Capturing` instead of `@Mocked`, every `Logger` that is created during the test run will be associated with one you annotated. So the following works:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldLogWarn(@Capturing final Logger logger) throws Exception {
   // This really ought to be a Verifications block instead
   new Expectations() {{
     logger.warn(anyString);
   }};
   MyClass my = new MyClass();
   my.foo(); 
 }
```

As a side note, if all you want to do is verify that a method is called, it's better to use [Verifications](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Verifications.html) instead, since that is what it is intended for. So your code would look like this:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldLogWarn(@Capturing final Logger logger) throws Exception {
   MyClass my = new MyClass();
   my.foo(); 
   new Verifications() {{
     logger.warn(anyString);
   }};
 }
```

### Alternatively, you can use `@Mocked` on both `Logger` and `LoggerFactory`

In some cases, `@Capturing` won't work as intended due to intricacies of how the annotation works. Fortunately, you can also get the same effect by using `@Mocked` on both `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` like so:

```
 @Test
 public void shouldLogWarn(@Mocked final LoggerFactory loggerFactory, @Mocked final Logger logger) throws Exception {
   MyClass my = new MyClass();
   my.foo(); 
   new Verifications() {{
     logger.warn(anyString);
   }};
 }
```

---

**Note:** JMockit 1.34 through 1.38 [has a bug](https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/507) that prevents this from working with `slf4j-log4j12`, and possibly other dependencies of SLF4J. Upgrade to 1.39 or later if you run into this bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In addition in this case had to add '@Mocked LoggerFactory unused' because without it got NPE while real LoggerFactory was trying to work with mocked logger.

Comment: @mergoth Mocking a LoggerFactory is unnecessary if your code uses the static method. So `private static final Logger LOG =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);` Actually, I see that you are using it, so I'm not sure why you're needing a mocked instance of LoggerFactory. I use the exact same thing in my code, but don't need to mock LoggerFactory.

Comment: if LoggerFactory is not mocked, the getLogger() method tries to get logger instance and eventually dies with NPE, while putting already mocked Logger instance to a non-null enforced Map in the deep of logback lib.

Comment: @mergoth What version of SLF4J are you using? In 1.7.21 (the latest as of this writing), LoggerFactory is a final class with a private constructor. Looking into the source code for `getLogger()`, it doesn't seem to ever instantiate `LoggerFactory` (and obviously, it can't since it's private). There must be something else going on.

Comment: @mergoth I tried your SSCCE of MyClass with the current solution and it runs correctly on my machine (after making `log` final, since it's being referenced inside an inner class). There must be something else going wrong in your real example.

Comment: I'm using SLF4J version 1.7.12 apparently. Not sure how exactly this is happening, but if I ever remove `@Mocked LoggerFactory` from test - it starts crushing with:     `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 ....
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:144)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getLogger(LoggerContext.java:45)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:304)`